# Is this the right usage of respectively? Is this sentence clear?

Tags: word-usage, lists, suspended-hyphen

Is this the correct use of respectively?

> 40% weight was placed on client evaluations, with 30%, 20%, and 10% weight attributed to manager, peer, and self-evaluations respectively.

Also is it appropriate to only say "evaluation" once in this case? Is there a better way to phrase this sentence?

Comment: It is clear to me.  Respectively is used correctly.  You don't need to say evaluation after manager and peer.  Is there a better way?  There usually is, but I can't think of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed the correct usage of *respectively*, though there should be a comma before it.

For ease of understanding, I'd also recommend listing the types of evaluations *before* listing the corresponding percentages:

> 40% of the score was based on the client evaluations; the manager, peer, and self-evaluations made up 30%, 20%, and 10% of the score, respectively.

Or even dropping the "respectively" structure, and instead writing:

> Client evaluations made up 40% of the score; manager evaluations, 30%; peer evaluations, 20%; self-evaluations, the remaining 10%.

Comment: While I appreciate that you marked my answer as accepted, you might want to wait a bit longer. That gives a chance for other possible answers to be posted; it gives a chance to see if other people agree or disagree with this answer; etc.